# Cannot mount internal SD card in Semaphore CWM Recovery v5.0.2.7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, clockworkmod-recovery

I Installed CyanogenMod 10.1.2 in my Galaxy S I9000 using Semaphore CWM Recovery v5.0.2.7  following this guide: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_galaxysmtd

Before flashing the new ROM I made a backup using Semaphore CWM.

After installing CyanongenMod I've noticed that I didn't saved my contacts inside my Google Acount so I tried to restore the backup I've made using CWM Recovery. An error occured while restoring and after that I can't boot in normal mode (I didn't remember the error message).

When tried entering in the recovery mode to reinstall the CyanogenMod I got the following error messages:

> E:failed to open /etc/recovery.fstab (No such file or directory)
>
> E:unknown volume for path [/cache/recovery/command]
>
> E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/command
>
> E:unknown volume for path [/cache/recovery/log]
>
> E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
>
> E:unknown volume for path [/cache/recovery/last_log]
>
> E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
>
> E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
>
> E:unknown volume for path [/cache/recovery/command]

And when I try to install CyanogenMod from the SD card I got the following errors:

> E:unknown volume for path [/sdcard/]
>
> E:Can't mount /sdcard/

I tried reinstalling CWM Recovery but nothing changed. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue and flash a new ROM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've followed the guide in this page and reinstalled a stock version of Android: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1196179

Then I reinstalled CWM Recovery and flashed CyanogenMod.